# Off Center Line Rotation

Tags: math, angle

So I have a rectangle that rotates around its center and I want a way to make a line around each of its edges. It rotates in radians and the center point is a vector that contains its location which is what I want to use to get the line points which are also vectors.[image: Diagram]
What needs to happen is that the line points have to constantly change depending on the rotation to align with the edges of the rectangle. I'm sure there is a formula for this but how can I use it for off-center rotation like this?

Comment: Not clear enough to me, I cannot determine the axis of rotation, I need a point and a direction. I cannot determine the position of the (unrotated) rectangle.

Comment: Not clear enough to me, I cannot determine the axis of rotation, I need a point and a direction. I cannot determine the position of the (unrotated) rectangle.

Comment: the position of the rectangle is the center and it is also the point at which it rotates from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rectangle vertices have coordinates

```
X = center_x +- width/2
Y = center_y +- height/2
```

After rotation by angle `Fi` coordinates change:

```
New_X = center_x + (X - center_x) * Cos(Fi) - (Y - center_y) * Sin(Fi)
New_Y = center_y + (X - center_x) * Sin(Fi) + (Y - center_y) * Cos(Fi)
```

Choose all pairs of neighbor vertices (modifying +- signs) and get new coordinates

Comment: Welcome to the world of [rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions)